# How to see that this is a filtration of a vector space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a finite dimensional vector space $W$, a *filtration* of $W$ is a family of subspaces $(F_x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ of $W$ such that $F_y \subset F_x$ whenever $y \geq x$, and such that $F_x = \{0\}$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a number field $k$ and let $D_1,...,D_r$ be effective Cartier divisors on $X$ that intersect properly (I think its definition is not needed for this question), and that $\cap^r_{i=1}D_i$ is nonempty. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbf{t} = (t_1,...,t_r) \in (\mathbb{R}^+)^r \setminus \{0\}$, we define
$$N(\mathbf{t},x) := \{\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{N}^r: t_1b_1+...+t_rb_r \geq x\}.$$

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf over $X$ such that $h^0(\mathcal{L}) \geq 1$. We define the ideal $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},x)$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by
$$\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},x) := \sum_{\mathbf{b} \in N(\mathbf{t},x)}\mathcal{O}_X\left( -\sum_{i=1}^r b_iD_i \right),$$
and let
$$F(\mathbf{t})_x = H^0(X,\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},x)).$$
**Question.** How do we show that $(F(\mathbf{t})_x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is a filtration of the vector space $H^0(X, \mathcal{L})$?

I have no idea what's going on here. For example, why are the ideals $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},x)$ defined like this? One thing I can say though, is that if $x \leq y$, then obviously $N(\mathbf{t},y) \subset N(\mathbf{t},x)$. And so the terms in the sum $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},y)$ will be contained in the terms in the sum $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{t},x)$, but how does that affect taking tensor product with $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: What lead you to this? It seems likely this is from something you're reading - where is this from? Next, the basic tools here are that the global sections functor is left exact, tensoring with an invertible sheaf is exact, and there's an injective map $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\to\mathcal{O}_X$. Try combining these.

Comment: @KReiser This is the argument used in a new result of Ru and Vojta and can be found in Chapter 7 of Ru's book on Nevanlinna theory, 2021 edition. Setting $D_{\mathbf{b}} =\sum_{i=1}^rb_iD_i$, we have an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-D_{\mathbf{b}}) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow i_*(\mathcal{O}_{D_{\mathbf{b}}}) \rightarrow 0,$$ where $i$ is the canonical inclusion. Taking sum over $\mathbf{b} \in N(\mathbf{t},x)$ and then tensoring with $\mathcal{L}$ would preserve exactness, and it remains to take global sections and compare the exact sequences for $x$ and $y$, right?